# Rails: Automatically running failed tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, minitest, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I frequently run "rake", see some tests fail, and have to manually cut-and-paste failures into a new command, "ruby SomeTest -n some_test_method" to run individual tests. Is there any way to automate that?

It feels like standard behaviour for IDEs to show errors and allow quick re-playing, so I wonder if anyone has figured out how to do it quickly on the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guard is what you're looking for:

```
https://github.com/guard/guard
```

Guard watches the filesystem for changes and automatically triggers a command.  With guard you can automatically run tests the second they're saved.

For minitest use:

```
https://github.com/guard/guard-minitest
```

For test unit:

```
https://github.com/guard/guard-test
```

For Rspec:

```
https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec
```

Comment: Guard re-runs tests when files are changed, but I'm looking to re-run failed tests after a global "rake test" fails.

Comment: You don't need to do `rake test`, you can just run all of your tests in guard (I believe by hitting 'enter') - any failures will then be re-attempted when you make changes in your project.

Comment: In guard-rspec it does maintain a list of failed specs.  May be something similar in the minitest guard.